# Dictionary.ContainsKey StringComparer.Ordinal

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

I'm working with a Dictionary in C# with .NET 3.5.  I've created a `Dictionary<string, int>` object and passed in the `StringComparer.Ordinal` equality comparer.  When I do the following code, however, I don't get what I would expect:

```
Dictionary<string, int> theDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
theDictionary.Add("First", 1);
bool exists = theDictionary.ContainsKey("FIRST");    // equals true, when it should not
```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: It evaluates to false on my machine. Could you double-check that you’re reading the correct value?

Comment: looks like a PICNIC problem. mmmm
It's actually a little confusing when you see "System.OrdinalComparer".  makes you think that you really did supply StringComparer.Ordinal, because you don't see "IgnoreCase" anywhere...

Comment: @AustinSalonen `StringComparer.Ordinal` is independent of language.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you didn't use [StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx)?

This code prints false for me with C# v3.5 compiler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    static class Program
    {
      static void Main()
      {
        Dictionary<string, int> theDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
        theDictionary.Add("First", 1);
        bool exists = theDictionary.ContainsKey("FIRST");

        Console.WriteLine(exists);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is little difficult to override if we have to read a dictionary which is coming from a 3rd party library.